# jQuery Ajax send twice the second submit , three times the third submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a comment system for my blogging site.Here user can post a question and others can give reply to it.Also users can give comment to each reply like stack overflow.Problem is after first comment ,second comment gets submitted twice,third comment gets submitted thrice and so on.How i can fix this issue ? thanks :)

***hrer var comment ,textarea and cmntholder all are collection of elements***

```
var comment=$('.cmnt');
var textarea=$('.answerComment');
var cmntholder=$('.cmntholder')
for(i=0;i<comment.length;i++){
    (function(i){
        $(comment[i]).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(comment[i]).hide();
            $(textarea[i]).show();
            $(textarea[i]).keypress(function(e){
                if(e.which=='13'){
                    $.ajax('../includes/verifycomment.php',{
                        data   :{
                            'comment_body'     :$(this).val(),
                            'userpost_post_id' : <?php echo $postid;?>,
                            'users_user_id'    : <?php echo $userdata->user_id; ?>,
                            'answers_answer_id':$(this).data('id')
                        },
                        datatype:'json',
                        method  :'POST',
                        success :function(response){
                              $(textarea[i]).html('');
                              $(textarea[i]).hide();
                              var obj=$.parseJSON(response);
                             alert('bal');
                              var str="<div class='stylecomment' >"+obj[0]['comment_body']+" --- <span style='color:#d3d3d3;font-size:13px;'>   commented by </span><a href='../includes/profile.php?user=<?php echo escape($userdata->username);?>'><?php echo escape($userdata->username);?></a> </div></div>";
                              $(cmntholder[i]).append(str);
                              $(comment[i]).show();
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
            $(this).hide();
        });
    })(i);
}
```

here is the issue :

[image]

Comment: it is supposed ot work as a closure. How this can cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because you are re-binding the keypress function to the DOM element/s each time the click event fires. This does not replace the current keypress event listener each time, it simply adds a new one. Thus, the first time you click it executes once, the second time, twice, etc. You can remove the event listener each time the click event is fired, right before you bind the new keypress listener to the textarea[i] to make sure that you only get one event to fire each time.
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

```
$(textarea[i]).unbind("keypress");
$(textarea[i]).keypress(function (e) {...});
```

This happens any time you define an event listener inside of an event listener, just FYI.

Comment: works like a charm..thanks a lot :). can you please shed some light on 'what re-binding ' is ?

Comment: Well, when I used the term "re-binding" it was probably the wrong word. The more accurate wording would be to say that you are "binding a new function to execute on the keypress event each time the click event is fired". If you think about the code execution, each time the comment[i] is clicked, it declares a new event handler function for textarea[i]. Since there *can be more than one* function attached to any given event, it does not overwrite the existing event handler function, it simply adds a new one on top of the existing one/s.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely with the "i" counter. It seems to be unnecessary to go through each comment because the only one available to submit is the most recent one, and that's why it submits the most recent one multiple times.

Comment: hrer var comment ,textarea and cmntholder all are collection of element that's why i had to use 'i'